# How to move other applications to background on startup

Tags: android, kill-process

I am new to Android. I am trying to write a app which will send all the other apps to background at their start up and then afterwards kill them. I tried to use `moveTaskToBack(true)` but this send my app to background not others.

```
servMng = (ActivityManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
                List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> list = servMng.getRunningAppProcesses();
                if(list != null){
                 for(int i=0;i<list.size();++i){
                  if("com.android.browser".matches(list.get(i).processName)){
                      moveTaskToBack(true);
                      servMng.killBackgroundProcesses(list.get(i).processName);
                      servMng.restartPackage(list.get(i).processName);

              }
```

For example, I want browser app to be sent to background but this will move my running app to background.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to using HOME button functionality.To send all activities to background.I don't think this is possible is not possible in android.

Why you are doing this? As when your application launch it automatically com to front.

Comment: I am doing this because I want to stop all the other apps when my app is running.If you know something please help me.